# How to lookup for Generice DataSource

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using Weblogic server to host the EJB application.

Now I have written code to lookup Datasource on server side which works fine
and search the Datasource if code look for specific name. See the line no 2 in below code.

```
dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/irisuatDS");
```

But my problem is I have 4 different environment let say Local, Dev, Stage and production. Is there any way where code can we written for generic DataSource. something like below lines without pointing to specific name.
When I use below piece of code it gives me error.

```
dataSource = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/irisuatDS");
dataSource = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

Please let me know how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: The usual thing thing to do is to use the same DS name in each environment, but the DataSource itself would point to the corresponding database (dev, test, prod etc).

Comment: ok thanks , I got the Idea